# Getting error while using parameterised like query in Python

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am getting the following error while trying to use like query for `sqlite3` db using python.

> Error:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.
```

I am explaining my query below.

```
rname = request.POST.get('rname')
keyword = '%' + rname + '%'
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM booking_meeting WHERE room_name LIKE ? ",(keyword))
```

Here I need to fetch value from table as per keyword. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Please stop using raw SQL for trivial queries like this.

Answer (score 1):

`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM booking_meeting WHERE room_name LIKE ? ",(keyword))`

`execute`'s second argument must be a tuple even if there is only one parameter:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM booking_meeting WHERE room_name LIKE ? ",(keyword,))
                                                                             # ^
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
keyword = '%"' + rname + '"%'
```

or

```
keyword = '%\'' + rname + '\'%'
```

spaces in your `keyword` might cause the 3 parameters recognized.